# Change route inside component according to its state. Is this possible?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular12

On an Angular 12 application I have the following component:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  result: boolean;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });

  }

  signUp() {

    if (this.form.valid) {

      this.userService.signUp({email: this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password).subscribe(
        
        (next) => { },

        (error) => { }

      )
    } 
  }    
}
```

The route of this component is `/signup`.

Is it possible to change the route to:

1. `/signup/success` with `result` variable set to `true`;
2. `/signup/failed` with `result` variable set to `false`.

Always within the same component ...

Comment: The usual suspect for this sort of thing is [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl) or [navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) if you want more control over passing in a state to the next component without URL encoding (this will fit your use case better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` provided by Angular.

Assuming you have configured your routes as below

`{path: 'signup/success', component: SuccessComponent }` and
`{path: 'signup/failed', component: FailureComponent }`

Add this to the constructor of `SignUpComponent`

`constructor(private router: Router) { }`

Now, your `signUp()` method would look something like this.

```
signUp() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.userService.signUp({email: this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password).subscribe(
        (next) => { this.router.navigate(['/signup/success', {result: true}]); },
        (error) => { this.router.navigate(['/signup/failed', {result: false}]); }
      )
    } 
  }
```

Now in order to retrieve the value of the `result` parameter in either the `SuccessComponent` or `FailureComponent`, you can use `ActivatedRoute` provided by Angular by injecting it in the constructor of these two components as shown below:

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }`

Now you can get the value of the `result` parameter in these components as shown below;

`resultValue = this.route.paramMap.get('result');`